# Folder Permissions for new partition - can't move files

Tags: partitioning, permissions

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.  I used the install CD to repartition my HD by resizing /dev/sda1 and creating /dev/sda3 as a Primary Partition.  I named it "Media".  When I reboot from HD, when I try to move files from the home directory to the new partition, I get an error message  "Error while copying.  The folder “TV” cannot be copied because you do not have permissions to create it in the destination."

The new partition shows up in Gparted as locked, with mount point /media/ian/Media and Label Media.

I want to move my media files from the boot partition to a separate partition.

Any advice?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/308801/no-permissions-on-new-partition?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Mina's answer, it would seem you don't have 'ownership' of the area. To solve this we'll use ´chown´ (change owner) and ´chgrp´ (change Group)

1. Type ´sudo chown /media/ian/Media ian' this makes you the owner, rather than it being 'owned' by the ´root´ account.
2. Type ´sudo chgrp /media/ian/Media $x´ where $x is tour group name. (It's likely just ian. If it's not, you probably already know what it is.) If you are unsure of your group name type ´ls -l ~´ and your group name will be the second 'name' column, next to 'ian'.

Note: In Linux Mint 17(and probably in Ubuntu 14.04) the owner-name and the group-name comes first i.e.

```
sudo chown ian /media/ian/Media
```

&

```
sudo chgrp $x /media/ian/Media
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sudo!

Type in a terminal `gksudo nautilus` and move your files from there